# I keep getting 2 values back when I count my rows and set them.....php

Tags: php

basically I am trying to count my rows and display the number foreach using php. Here is the code:

```
  foreach (range(1, mysql_num_rows($result)) as $number) :  
  foreach($user as $User): 
  echo $number;
  <? echo $User['name']; ?>
  endforeach;
  endforeach;
```

The result that I am getting is that it doubles the web result, it does not output correctly. Here is the code:

```
  1 keny
  1 leny
  2 keny
  2 leny
```

How can I output my result correctly?

Comment: I was thinking 2 foreach states...

Comment: why not count the results, then from there, increment them and concatenate them side by side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a `for` loop ?

```
$j=0;
for($i=1; $i<=mysql_num_rows($result); $i++)
{
 echo $i." ".$user[$j]['name'];
 $j++;
}
```

Comment: @user3561965, Idk why it is weird, let me explain. The `for` loop is same as your `foreach` in this context , I am simply adding the `$user` array with the index starting from `$j` , as the names are stored on your `$user` array in this form.. `$user[0]['name']='keny';` and `$user[1]='leny';` .. so on.. and thus incrementing `$j` further. As you can see there is no need of two loop structures.

Answer (score 1):

Because the first foreach repeats twice. Try to do this:

```
$unique = array_combine( range(1, mysql_num_rows($result) ), $user);

foreach($unique as $num => $us ){
 echo $num . ' - ' . $us;
}
```